# Stop setInterval until action not performed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

Is it possible that we could stop setInterval means next interval will call only when first event completed.

I want to load next image only when previous image loaded.This event should work only after mouse over.But if next image is large in size then next interval is calling in my case..i want to stop interval until last image not loaded.

This is my code:

```
jQuery('.product').on('mouseover', function(){
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        if (counter === product_images.length) {
            counter = 0;
        }

        // selector.addClass('hidden');
        loading_image.removeClass('hidden');
        selector.attr('src', 'localhost/product/' + product_images[counter]);
        var loadImage = new Image();
        loadImage.src = selector.attr('src');
        loadImage.onload = function() {console.log('after load');
        loading_image.addClass('hidden');
        // selector.removeClass('hidden');
        selector.show();
    };
    counter = counter + 1;
}, 1000);
```

How we can stop setInterval or prevent it to go next interval even task of last interval is not completed.Not for clearInterval,It should be continue(setInterval) if first task completed.

Please help me.

Comment: i guess you're looking for `clearInterval(timer);`

Comment: not for clearInterval setInterval should be continue but stop only for that movement until first task not completed.

Comment: you need to use callback and/or promises for that

Comment: @atmd..i dont know how it will work could u please give a short code description so that i could understand or use that.

Comment: why is your setinterval inside `mouseover`?? this code will create new intervals everytime you hover on `.product`

Comment: it will be inside becz image will change inside after mouseover...Thanks @Boss

Comment: thats the point.. if you hover it three times there will be three handlers running independently.

Comment: but problem is that i want to stop setInterval ..how is it possible..Thanks @Boss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the below code. this may work,

```
var flag = 1;
jQuery('.product').on('mouseover', function(){
    if(typeof timer != "undefined")
        clearInterval(timer);
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        if(flag){
            if (counter === product_images.length) {
                counter = 0;
            }
            loading_image.removeClass('hidden');
            selector.attr('src', 'localhost/product/' + product_images[counter]);
            flag = 0;
            var loadImage = new Image();
            loadImage.src = selector.attr('src');
            loadImage.onload = function() {
                console.log('after load');
                loading_image.addClass('hidden');
                selector.show();
                flag = 1;
            };
            counter = counter + 1;
        }
}, 1000);
```

NOTE: I have not tested this code.